# What are the limitations of aquafaba as an egg white substitute?

Tags: substitutions, egg-whites, chickpeas

I learned recently that aquafaba is claimed to be usable as an egg white substitute, able to be whipped to form stiff peaks, etc.

Now an egg-white-and-cottage-cheese omelette is a frequent breakfast of mine. So it was with great experimental enthusiasm that I mixed up some aquafaba with cottage cheese, and set about cooking it as usual...only to end up with aquafaba and cottage cheese soup. :(

What is a more realistic assessment of where aquafaba can be substituted for egg whites? Or is there possibly some modification that would make an aquafaba-and-cottage-cheese omelette possible?

Comment: Related question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/107640/69341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is useful to think of aquafaba as a egg-white substitute. Rather, you should think of whipped aquafaba as a replacement for French meringue, in cases you are not relying on it setting under heat.

So, when you need a vegan foam, you can try aquafaba (after whipping) to get the right texture. To regard it as a general replacement for egg whites is an exaggeration.