# Make aquafabe from scratch - can the soaking water be used for cooking

Tags: substitutions, egg-whites

I would like to make aquafaba from white beans. I am going to soak the dried beans for a couple of hours and then boil them, the remaining water should be aquafaba.

I wonder if I need to change the liquid in which the beans have been soaked or if this will make the aquafaba have less of the desired properties.

I think I read once that you need to change the water if making aquafaba from chickpeas.

I would guess from this response
[What is the food chemistry of aquafaba?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107640/what-is-the-food-chemistry-of-aquafaba)
that changing the water does not really matter, but I would like to ask nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly when you talk about changing liquid, you mean boiling the beans in a water different from the one in which you soaked them? In that case yes, generally speaking it is recommended to boil all your legumes in a different water, because cooking them in the soaking water will make them less digestible, but it shouldn't have any influence on the composition/consistency of your aquafaba.
The most important is the cooking water, because it is during this process that the carbohydrates and proteins of the legume will transfer to the water and make your aquafaba.