# Is the liquid inside the canned chickpeas meant for consumption?

Tags: canning, curry, chickpeas

Can the liquid inside the canned chickpeas be consumed?

Should I drain it or add it to the chickpea-curry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the food chemistry of aquafaba?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107640/what-is-the-food-chemistry-of-aquafaba)

Comment: @user366312, are you intending to ask a food safety question?  Because that's what your title expresses, but your main text says "should I".  Please be more clear.

Comment: @bob1 actually, the rules of duplicates are "only when the question matches". If it's a different question, it's not closed, even if the answers would duplicate one another, or if the answer to one would imply the answer to the other.

Comment: Adam Ragusea addresses bean juice https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfgDxMFn0X4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you meant to ask a food safety question, otherwise this is a duplicate:

The liquid in the can with your chickpeas is food safe; otherwise, there would be no way for the beans themselves to be safe.  There are two reasons you wouldn't want to eat it:

1. The bean broth can be very salty, as some canned beans use the brine method
2. Canned bean broth can be [high in BPA](https://www.consumerreports.org/cro/2012/05/concern-over-canned-foods/index.htm) depending on a number of factors

Comment: My understanding is that draining the liquid also reduces the probability of flatulence, as well.

Comment: This is true, the fermentable carbs in the beans (AKA FODMAPs) are water soluble so canned beans, when drained, will have less fermentable carbs. Regular not canned chickpeas are very high in galacto-oligosacharrides.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on what you’re making whether you want to use it or not.

If you’re cooking something that just calls for chickpeas, you probably don’t want to use it.  Especially if they tell you to rinse off the beans if you’re using canned.

But because the liquid is high in protein, it can be used as an egg white replacement.  (Look up ‘aquafaba’).    You just have to beware of an increased amount of salt that you may need to adjust the recipe for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it can be very useful, as another answer states. We use chickpea aquafaba to make meringues, and in other recipes as an egg replacer, and it works quite well. Look up recipes for a few ideas!

Here is one from a quick search: https://www.sprinklebakes.com/2020/04/chickpea-water-or-aquafaba-meringue.html

Also, if you want to avoid exposure to plastics, you can cook your own in a pressure cooker, like an Instapot, in pretty short order, and it's very economical.

Comment: We used this in cakes!